# Are terminology questions that apply to more than one game on topic?

Tags: discussion, closing, terminology

I have asked a question to find out what the term is for 3D objects that appear suddenly and disappear suddenly in 3D games when the player moves towards or away from them.

[What is the standard term used to describe objects appearing from nowhere in 3D games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266326/what-is-the-standard-term-used-to-describe-objects-appearing-from-nowhere-in-3d)

Someone commented:

> We explicitly do not allow terminology questions spanning the breadth of gaming. If you want to know what this is for a specific game, alright, ask that.

In light of this comment, even though I could not locate anything on the tour that explicitly states this, I am concerned that my question will be closed, though an answer has been posted, and is helpful, I do not feel that it answers the question adequately, so I would be prepared to take action to prevent question closure if necessary.

Should I edit my question to mention a specific game, or a list of games that have the described behaviour? Or can I leave it as is?

Comment: Why do you feel that @twobugs' answer isn't adequate? It's actually one of the best answers of its kind

Comment: @badp The answer doesn't provide a verb that can be used to describe the behaviour, "Drawn" is too general, since  everything on the screen is being drawn, to say that you can see objects being drawn might not be clear when what you're actually referring to is the sudden appearance of the objects from out of nowhere. I'm quite surprised that the question was put on hold for being too broad.

Comment: Well as you just explained the answer doesn't give you a verb because there really isn't one. Technically speaking what's happening is either "frustrum culling" or "the object is entering the viewing frustrum through the far base"; the former causes the object to not be rendered at all and the latter means that the object was rendered but it became invisible due to the perspective transformation anyway. good luck having anyone who didn't take a 3D rendering course understand what you're saying.

Comment: @badp I think that the behaviour that I have described in my question is something that anyone that has played a 3D game is capable of understanding. I will have to accept that I wont get an answer on the gaming stack exchange. Thanks for those technical terms, I'll look into that.